# How do rigid type variables work in the context of Monads?

Tags: haskell, casting, monads, higher-order-functions, algebraic-data-types

Say I have a Monad `data Concurrent a = Concurrent ((a -> Action) -> Action)` and a type `Action` which allows various possible `IO Actions`.

Say I wanted to write a function `action :: Concurrent a -> Action`, effectively writing a custom unwrap. A first step might be something like writing a function `action2 :: ((a -> Action) -> Action) -> Action`

I have a handful of questions:
It is my understanding that `a` is a rigid type variable, e.g. a type variable that will be coerced to some type by the compiler.

So that makes `((a -> Action) -> Action)` a function (lets call it f1), which accepts a function of type `(a -> Action)`, and returns an Action, for *some arbitrary type a*, and `((a -> Action) -> Action) -> Action`, a function that accepts the above function f1, runs it, and returns the result.

Assuming the above is correct my questions really are:

How does this make sense in the context of a Monad? Say I have a function:

```
stringToAction :: (String -> Action)
stringToAction [] = Stop
stringToAction x = Atom $ putStr x
```

so `:t stringToAction` fulfills the contract of (a -> Action)
however :t stringToAction "7" has type `(String -> Action) -> String -> Action`

Do I have to write a helper function of type `(a -> Action) -> a -> Action` (e.g.)

```
higherOrderStringToAction :: (String -> Action) -> String -> Action
higherOrderStringToAction f x = f x
```

And then call that on the passed function (a -> Action) ?

```
stringToActionHelper = higherOrderStringToAction stringToAction
```

Do I have to write a different set of such helper functions for every possible type of `a` that I wish to handle?

And then, even more worryingly, do I have to handle all of those in my Monad Instance definition? e.g

how does `Concurrent 7` know how to convert 7 to an Action? Do I have to interrogate the type of `a` in my `>>=` definition and branch? How would I even do that?

Or am I (and this honestly seems likely) completely missing the point here and/or straight up thinking of this wrong?

Comment: It's not too clear what you are worrying about. You are saying you have a monad. Can you show the instance definition?

Comment: "It is my understanding that a is a rigid type variable, e.g. a type variable that will be coerced to some type by the compiler." I'm not sure what this means, types are not coerced by the compiler to other types unless you ask for it explicitly. Or perhaps you mean something else by "coerced" and "rigid". Rigidity and flexibility and concepts related to typechecking, but these concepts seem to completely unrelated to the question. It seems like you simply have a type error somewhere... you should include a minimum working example.

Answer (score 1):

> Say I have a Monad `data Concurrent a = Concurrent ((a -> Action) -> Action)` and a type `Action` which allows various possible `IO Actions`.

I'm going to assume that you put "IO Actions" in backticks for no reason. I do not know if you have a solid model of what's going on in your head, but since Haskell is a pure language the meaning of `IO x` is "a program which, when run, produces an `x`" (in other words the Haskell solution to functional I/O is to engage in metaprogramming rather than other programming.) So it sounds like in practice `Action` is going to be something like a type synonym for `IO ()` or something.

A Hoogle search for `(a -> IO x) -> IO x` reveals that this is the output type of `withMVar m` and related to the `fixIO` type too. In other words: your `Concurrent` is all about wrapping up some value of type `a` and holding it for later.

We can see this most explicitly if we define `data C b a = C ((a -> b) -> b)` so that your `Concurrent` is actually just the special case `C Action`. The trick here is that this function type `forall b. (a -> b) -> b` is actually the Church encoding of the `Identity` monad `newtype Identity a = Identity {runIdentity :: a}`. In turn we can say the more general monad is:

```
instance Monad (C b) where
    return x = C ($ x)
    (C w_wx) >>= my_x = my_x (w_wx id)
```

So what you've written for `Concurrent` is essentially a special case of the identity monad.

> so `:t stringToAction` fulfills the contract of (a -> Action) however :t stringToAction "7" has type `(String -> Action) -> String -> Action`

False. `stringToAction "7"` has type `Action` as it results from a function of type `String -> Action` applied to a value of type `String`.

> Do I have to write a helper function of type `(a -> Action) -> a -> Action`

What you wrote has a name, it is the function called `id` or more specifically its type specialization `($)`. Furthermore this type above does not have the type that you want to shove into your `data Concurrent a = Concurrent ((a -> Action) -> Action)` constructor. Instead you want something like `($ "myString") :: (String -> Action) -> Action` to embed that string into your identity monad.

> how does Concurrent 7 know how to convert 7 to an Action? Do I have to interrogate the type of `a` in my `>>=` definition and branch? How would I even do that?

It doesn't. Your `Concurrent` monad is actually just the `Identity` monad and the process of converting a value like `7` to an `Action` is done by the `Int -> Action` function that you pass in to the argument. (For that matter, if you write `Concurrent 7` you will get a nasty error from GHC saying "I didn't know that the type `(a -> Action) -> Action` is an element of the `Num` typeclass, what the heck is going on?!"